# Memory issues in C code or Arduino limitations?

Tags: c, json, rest, memory, arduino

I'm working on a project with an Arduino Yùn module. I am currently trying to create JSON from the Arduino to return. The creation of this JSON happens in a nested for-loop. I'm using the aJson Arduino library (https://github.com/interactive-matter/aJson).

When I build the Arduino it gets sent correctly the first time. When I do a REST call after that I just get an empty line `\r\n` (this is most likely the empty line after the HTTP response header)...

I'm not sure if I'm dealing with memory issues here, or if there's any other problem going on. I'm very used to work with Objective Oriented languages, I know C, but since it has no garbage collection freeing memory and such is not all that clear to me...

This is my code of the method which creates and sends the JSON:

```
void getAll(YunClient client) {
    aJsonObject *root, *object;
    root = aJson.createArray();

    int i = 0;    
    for(i; i < 4; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        for(j; j < 3; j++) {   
          aJson.addItemToArray(root, object = aJson.createObject());
          aJson.addNumberToObject(object, "test", 1);
          //should I do a free(object); here?
      }
    }       

  //headers
  //client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
  client.println("Status: 200");
  client.println("Content-Type: application/javascript");
  client.println("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  //client.print("\r\n");
  client.println();

  // Send feedback to client
  char* result = aJson.print(root);
  Serial.println(result);
  client.println(result);

  free(root);
  free(result);  
}
```

As you can see, inside te nested for-loop I'm not sure if I should free memory there.

When I do the REST call the first time I get this:
[image]

The second time I get this (BUT my Arduino doesn't jam/ crash, other functiosn keep working and it still sends the data, it just seems to be empty...):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be using `free` for the aJson structs!
How do you know what is in these structs? Check the library docs on how to free.

I found this on the page you linked:

> Finished? Delete the root (this takes care of everything else).
>
> `aJson.deleteItem(root);`

And also this (since you are using an aJson list):

> Lists are easily handled in aJson, to create a list you can simply use
>   the provided API functions:
>
> `aJson.create<TYPE>Array(objects,24);`
>
> You simply pass a array of the respective type: `char*[]`, `int[]` and so
>   on.
>
> aJSON doesn't make any assumptions about what order you create things
>   in. You can attach the objects, as above, and later add children to
>   each of those objects with
>
> `aJson.addItemToArray()`
>
> or remove them with
>
> `aJson.deleteItemFromArray()` - which also deletes the objects, or 
>   `aJson.detachItemFromArray()` - which does not free the memory
>
> As soon as you call aJson.print(), it renders the structure to text.